# ffmpeg alternative to setpts for making a survey gif

Tags: ffmpeg, time-lapse

I have a 30fps video that is 234 minutes long and want to shrink it down to 2 minutes.  `1-(234-2)/234)` gives me 0.0085 which I use

`ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf setpts=PTS*0.0085,palettegen palette.png`

followed by

`ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i palette.png --filter_complex setpts=PTS*0.0085,paletteuse survey.gif`

Actually making the gif is excruciatingly slow compared to extracting the desired frames into a massive directory of png's which I can then combine with `convert` into a gif.  Aside from my main question, it doesn't seem like ImageMagick's convert supports user supplied palette files.

I understand that PTS is just adjusting how long a single frame is shown in a video but setpts has felt like the only reliably precise way of cutting the source.mp4 down.

I looked at `framestep` and it is much better for speed but I couldn't figure out an ideal value for `framestep` that wouldn't make the resulting gif step from one frame to the next like what I would get from using `convert` and a delay of 0.5 between frames.

Aside from above, these survey are meant to quickly scan through hours of video for various points of concern in a gif format able to be uploaded privately to imgur or giphy so others on my team could review them remotely and without ftp/dropbox/etc.

Comment: Do you wish to retain all frames and cycle through them in 2 mins, or pick just enough frames to have a 2 min 30 fps GIF? You mention `0.5` delay in relation to `convert` - is that 0.5 seconds per frame - which would indicate 240 frames to be selected from the video.

Comment: I just want to select enough to cover 2.5 minutes.  I have made these another way and they are epilepsy inducing but consistent enough to go back to the original minute in question.  As for the delay it is a bit confusing as that affects ticks per second and not frames per second.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a 30 fps 2.5m GIF, use

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(n,trunc(234/2.5)))',palettegen" palette.png
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0]select='not(mod(n,trunc(234/2.5)))',setpts=N/30/TB[v];[v][1]paletteuse" survey.gif
```